# PWA TypeError: Failed to fetch

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to install PWA on my website. Here is my Service worker:

```js
const CACHE_NAME = 'cache_v1';

self.addEventListener('install', async event => {
    self.skipWaiting();
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
    event.respondWith(
        caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then(function(cache) {
            if (navigator.onLine) {
                return fetch(event.request).then(function(response) {
                    if (event.request.method === 'GET') {
                        cache.put(event.request, response.clone());
                    }
                    return response;
                });
            } else {
                return cache.match(event.request).then(function (response) {
                    return response;
                });
            }
        }),
    );
});
```

This throws me an error:

```
TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

And warning:

```
Site cannot be installed: Page does not work offline. Starting in Chrome 93, the installability criteria is changing, and this site will not be installable. See https://goo.gle/improved-pwa-offline-detection for more information
```

How can I fix them?

Answer (score 0):

> Happy to help brother - you have not mentioned any files to be cached but you are fetching files that's why its giving errors try mine file:
> [service worker.js](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bf4hW5dUpxEExOEXZmvcqXzzlfaNKYco/view?usp=sharing)